# Trimming down type information in Scala when implementing immutable data types

Tags: scala

I was wondering if there's some sort of way of keeping the verbosity levels down when coding a simple BST in Scala:

```
sealed class BST[K <: Ordered[K], V]    
final case class Empty[K <: Ordered[K], V]
final case class Node[K <: Ordered[K], V](key : K, value : V, left :  BST[K, V], right : BST[K, V])

object BST {
  def size[K <: Ordered[K], V](bst: BST[K, V]): Int = bst match {
    case Empty => 0
    case Node(_, _, left, right) => 1 + size(left) + size(right)
  }
}
```

An equivalent definition in F# would be something like:

```
module BST =
  type t<K' : comparison, 'V> =
    | Empty
    | Node of K * V * t<K, V> * t<K, V>

  let rec size = function
    | Empty -> 0
    | Node(_, _, left, right) -> 1 + (size left) + (size right)
```

What I find particularly problematic is having to repeat for all functions the same yaddayadda regarding the generic parameters and actual parameter types. Is there some way to trim this stuff down?

Comment: prefer `Ordering` to `Ordered`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to define functions as operations in some implicitly fused class:

```
sealed class BST[K: Ordering, V]
final case class Empty[K: Ordering, V]() extends BST[K, V]
final case class Node[K: Ordering, V](key: K, value: V, left: BST[K, V], right: BST[K, V]) extends BST[K, V]


object BST {    
  import Ordering.Implicits._

  implicit class BSTOps[K: Ordering, V](val bst: BST[K, V]){
    def size: Int = bst match {
      case Empty() => 0
      case Node(_, _, left, right) => 1 + left.size + right.size
    }

    def :+(kv: (K, V)): BST[K, V] = {
      val (key, value) = kv
      bst match {
        case Empty() => Node(key, value, Empty(), Empty())
        case node@Node(nodeKey, _, _, _) => if (nodeKey > key)
          node.copy(left = node.left :+ kv)
        else node.copy(right = node.right :+ kv)

      }
    }
  }
}
```